# Spring AOP - Jboss : Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jboss

I am trying to pointcut every db connection before any user access and do business operations on database and write client_info as username to db. With this way i would know who executed the sql on database side.

This is my Aspect;

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ConnectionAspect {

    @Around("execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))")
    public Object proxyConnection(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        setClientInfo(result, false);
        return result;
    }

}
```

When i run the code in development server it works and there is no problem. ( With In tomcat and application side datasource )
**But when i run in the test server ( With in the JBoss and ApplicationServer based datasource ) the application do not start and gives the exception below ( Jboss Logs )**

```
2019-12-26 10:47:07,030 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in VFS resource ["/content/myproject.war/WEB-INF/classes/tr/com/aurora/myproject/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#661945d5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#661945d5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [tr/com/aurora/myproject/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in VFS resource ["/content/myproject.war/WEB-INF/classes/tr/com/aurora/myproject/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#661945d5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#661945d5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [tr/com/aurora/myproject/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in VFS resource ["/content/myproject.war/WEB-INF/classes/tr/com/aurora/myproject/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#661945d5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#661945d5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [tr/com/aurora/myproject/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:203)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#661945d5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [tr/com/aurora/myproject/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:626)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [tr/com/aurora/myproject/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:473)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:355)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
    ... 137 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:459)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    ... 150 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/as/connector/subsystems/datasources/WildFlyDataSource
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    ... 155 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource from [Module "deployment.myproject.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 157 more
```

I have a spring boot application and using hibernate. My application works on tomcat in development server and works on Jboss on test server. So in development server i m creating datasource on application side but in the test server i m using jboss's pre created datasource with jndi name.

Library and application versions

- Spring boot : 2.0.8.RELEASE
- Hibernate : 5.2.17.Final
- Jboss : 14.0.11.Final-redhat-00001
- Oracle

**Edit**

My Jboss DataSource configuration in `domain.xml` profile `ha`;

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDevDS" statistics-enabled="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.150:1521:myProjectSchema</connection-url>
        <driver>OracleDriver</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
            <initial-pool-size>5</initial-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>150</max-pool-size>
            <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>***</user-name>
            <password>***</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
            <background-validation>true</background-validation>
            <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
            <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
        </validation>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="OracleDriver" module="com.oracle"/>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Oracle driver declaration in `com/oracle/module.xml`

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc8.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Please share how you have resolved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

No one is answered this question and some others having same issue so i answered my own question. By the way it is a work around, i didn't found any solution to pointcut the jbosses datasource.

The problem is jboss using its own library to create datasource in its context and the default library of jboss is build using cglib proxy. Spring does not use cglib proxies as default. So springs proxy and jbosses proxy is conflicting.

I did not try to build my project using cglib proxies because devops process was not in my opinion.

So i did my job with aspecting the entity manager create method not the datasource create metod. Because entity manager is declared in my project and it is in control of spring.

Note: The entity manager is created once in a session but an entity manager is not restricted to use only one db connection. Entity manager uses the connection taken from the connection pool. BUT Jboss gives only one connection to one request. So it is same to point cut the connection create metod and entity manager ( session ) create metod.

There is my aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DbUserAspect {

    @Around("execution(javax.persistence.EntityManager javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(..))")
    public Object proxyConnection(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        EntityManager result = (EntityManager) joinPoint.proceed();

        if (SecurityUtils.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            setClientInfo(result, false);
            return createDbUserRemoveProxy(result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    
    private Object createDbUserRemoveProxy(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            EntityManager.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[]{EntityManager.class},
            (proxy, method, args) -> {
                if (method.getName().equals("close")) {
                    setClientInfo(entityManager, true);
                }
                return method.invoke(entityManager, args);
            }
        );
    }

    
    private void setClientInfo(EntityManager entityManager, boolean isClean) {
        Query query;
        try {
            query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("begin dbms_application_info.set_client_info(?); end;");
            if (!isClean) {
                query.setParameter(1, SecurityUtils.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                System.out.println("Connection : " + entityManager.hashCode() + " SET");
            } else {
                query.setParameter(1, null);
                System.out.println("Connection : " + entityManager.hashCode() + " CLEAN");
            }
            query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. I tried your suggestion - Around EntityManager, but is not working. What i am looking for is before running any query i need to run SP in context using same connection as "query" to be executed. Having Around EntityManager AOP - this point is called during initial server startup (connection pool setup), but not whenever new connection is established using that pool.

Comment: So, I am back to ground zero. Any advice would be helpful..

Comment: Actually i am calling a SP too. And entity manager create operation is running when new transaction scope ( session ) is created. I hope it helps. @Karthikeyan

Comment: I tried your snippet, still proxyConnection() is not called whenever i am making DAO call (entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery) )

Comment: @Karthikeyan Native queries are not controlled by entity manager maybe you need to pointcut another entity manager method

Comment: I have resolved his problem using BeanPostProcessor & DelegatingDatasource. Please find detailed answer i have updated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63186260/350705)